# calling repaint does not result in paint method being called in thread

Tags: java, swing

The following thread is being executed as a result of a mouse pressed event:

```
// simulates bouncing ball
class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {  
  int Horz = 200;  
  int Vert = 200;  
  int xDim = 10;  
  int yDim = 10;  
  private int xPos;  
  private int yPos;  
  private int dxPos;  
  private int dyPos;  

  // constructor - set initial ball position to where mouse clicked; deltas to random numbers
  public Ball(int startx, int starty)  
  {  
    xPos   = startx;  
    yPos   = starty;  
    dxPos =  (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 2);  
    dyPos =  (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 2);  
  }
  // logic to update position of ball
  public void move() {

    xPos += dxPos;
    yPos += dyPos;

    if (xPos < 0) {
      xPos = 0;
      dxPos = -dxPos;
    }
    if (xPos + xDim >= Horz) {
      xPos = Horz - xDim;
      dxPos = -dxPos;
    }
    if (yPos < 0) {
      yPos = 0;
      dyPos = -dyPos;
    }

    if (yPos + yDim >= Vert) {
      yPos = Vert - yDim;
      dyPos = -dyPos;
    }
  }
```

Run method is called which calls repaint

```
  @Override
  // run --- paint, sleep, update position - this is being executed
  public void run()     
  {  
    while (true)  
    {         
        System.out.println("I am in RUN");  
        repaint();  

        try
        {
            // sleep thread for 20 milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // interrupted
            System.out.println("Terminated prematurely due to interruption");
        }

        move();               
    }   
  }
```

But paint is not being called

```
     // draw ball at current position  
     @Override  
     public void paint( Graphics g )  
     {  
       // THIS IS NOT BEING EXECUTED  
       System.out.println("I am in paint");  

       super.paint( g );  
       g.setColor( Color.BLUE );   
       g.fillOval( xPos, yPos, 10, 10 );   
    }   
}
```

why is that ? isn't repaint supposed to call paint method ?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

Repaint doesn't immediately call paint; it schedules the component to be repainted, which will cause paint to be called as soon as the event queue can get to it. Most likely you are blocking the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by running the timer loop on it, so it cannot process paint events (or any other events). Run the loop on a different thread, or (easier, safer) replace it with a Swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```
Timer t = new Timer(20, (ActionEvent e) -> {
    move();
    repaint();
});
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Boan is right.
Though I would first take a look whether the thread was started:

```
Thread((Ball)ball);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Comment: I know the thread was started because I get inside the run method.  I'm not sure where in the Ball class I would put the code Boann suggested.

Comment: The swing Timer can go into Ball, so `move()` may be called. Mind that it is java 8 notation of the second argument to the Timer constructor; `new ActionListener() { ... }` for older javas.